# Issues with default values in android ListPreference

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-preferences, android-settings

I a strange issue with the ListPreference component of Android.  I am attempting to make a tic-tac-toe game for an Android course, and am attempting to add a ListPreference to select whether the user wants to play with an "X" or "O".  I am getting some strange behavior when trying to set the default value.  First, I will provide my code that works:

`res/xml/preferences.xml`:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <PreferenceCategory
            app:title="@string/preferences_category_game_settings_title" >

            <ListPreference
                app:title="@string/preferences_your_piece_title"
                app:defaultValue="x"
                app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"
                app:key="your_piece"
                app:entries="@array/preferences_your_piece_list"
                app:entryValues="@array/preferences_your_piece_stored" />

        </PreferenceCategory>

    </PreferenceScreen>
```

`res/values/arrays.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="preferences_your_piece_list">
        <item>@string/preferences_your_piece_x</item>
        <item>@string/preferences_your_piece_o</item>
    </array>

    <array name="preferences_your_piece_stored">
        <item>x</item>
        <item>o</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

`res/values/strings.xml`:

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="preferences_category_game_settings_title">Game Settings</string>
    <string name="preferences_your_piece_title">Your Game Piece</string>
    <string name="preferences_your_piece_x">X</string>
    <string name="preferences_your_piece_o">O</string>
</resources>
```

For some reason, this setup is very fragile.  If I make any sort of change to strings stored in `entryValues`, the default value doesn't work anymore.  The value in the app shows "Unset".  For example, if I simply capitalize the letters of the stored values, it breaks.

`res/xml/preferences`:

```xml
...
<ListPreference
    app:title="@string/preferences_your_piece_title"
    app:defaultValue="X"
...
```

`res/values/arrays.xml`:

```xml
...
<array name="preferences_your_piece_stored">
    <item>X</item>
    <item>O</item>
</array>
...
```

Capitalization is just one simple example.  If I change the values to ANY other string, other than 'x' and 'o', it breaks.  I also tried to move the `entryValues` to the strings file, as shown below.

`res/values/strings.xml`:

```xml
...
    <string name="preferences_your_piece_x_value">x</string>
    <string name="preferences_your_piece_o_value">o</string>
...
```

`res/values/arrays.xml`:

```xml
...
    <array name="preferences_your_piece_stored">
        <item>@string/preferences_your_piece_x_value</item>
        <item>@string/preferences_your_piece_o_value</item>
    </array>
...
```

`res/xml/preferences.xml`:

```xml
...
        <ListPreference
            app:title="@string/preferences_your_piece_title"
            app:defaultValue="@string/preferences_your_piece_x_value"
...
```

This implementation works, as shown, but as soon as I change the strings to ANYTHING but 'x' and 'o', it breaks.

In the code I have provided here, I am only showing one preference.  In my actual app, I have several.  The strange thing is: when I change the `entryValues` strings of this preference, it breaks the default values of ALL of the preferences.

As far as my backend code goes:

This is my fragment class:

```kotlin
class PreferencesFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
}
```

This is how I open the preferences screen with a menu item:

```kotlin
        val fragment = PreferencesFragment()
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
```

I have NOT yet accessed the shared preferences with `sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`

In terms of my build process, I am completely uninstalling the app from my phone before I re-start it from Android Studio with changes.  I have tried running Clean Project as well as Rebuild Project in Android Studio.

I cannot come up with any reason that the contents of strings would cause an element to break like this.  Any help would be EXTREMELY appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have resolved itself, somehow.  I left this project alone for a while, and when I came back, everything worked as I expected.  I've updated Android Studio since I wrote this question, so maybe there was a compiler bug?  Either way, I'm glad it worked out!